# Problems with MVVM, binding does not show

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to implement the Model View Viewmodel. However I can't get it to work.

This is my model and the base class:

```
namespace GridCity.GUI {
    class DateInfoModel : PropertyChangedBase {
        private string _Date = string.Empty;

        public string Date {
            get {
                return _Date;
            }
            set {
                if (_Date != value) {
                    _Date = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Date));
                    System.Console.WriteLine(_Date);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace GridCity.GUI {
    using System.ComponentModel;
    public abstract class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected internal void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            System.Console.WriteLine("OnPropertyChanged: " + propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my viewmodel:

```
namespace GridCity.GUI {
    class DateInfoViewModel : PropertyChangedBase {
        public DateInfoViewModel(DateInfoModel model) {
            Model = model;
        }
        public DateInfoModel Model { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GridCity.GUI.DateInfoView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridCity.GUI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="60" d:DesignWidth="150">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Content="{Binding Model.Date}"></Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Content="TEST"></Label>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I set `view.DataContext` in my MainWindow constructor:

```
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();

    DateInfoView view = new DateInfoView();
    Game.DateInfoModel = new DateInfoModel();
    DateInfoViewModel viewModel = new DateInfoViewModel(Game.DateInfoModel);

    view.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

I can see the second label (`TEST`), so the user control seems to work in theory. However I don't see anything in the first label. I can see outputs on the console however when `_Date` is changed and `OnPropertyChanged` is called.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where/how do you set `DataContext` to instance of `DateInfoViewModel`?

Comment: @dkozl: Sorry, forgot that part. I edited my question.

Comment: It answers one question but creates another one. What do you do with `view`? You create it, set its `DataContext` but don't use it after that. Are you sure the instance that you see is the same instance that you set `DataContext` of?

Comment: @dkozl: It's embedded in my MainWindow. How do I know it's the same instance?

Comment: @dkozl: Ah, it wasn't the same instance, but it works now that I gave it a name in xaml and used that name to assign the viewmodel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have two instances of `DateInfoView`. One that you define in XAML and one that you create in code. You set `DataContext` of the latter but then don't use it. You can fix it in one of few ways

**Solution 1**

Set `DataContext` of whole `Window` which will pass down `DataContext` value to your `UserControl`

```
public MainWindow() 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Game.DateInfoModel = new DateInfoModel();
    this.DataContext = new DateInfoViewModel(Game.DateInfoModel);
}
```

but as you say you want different context for different controls

**Solution 2**

Give `UserControl` name in XAML

```
<xx:DateInfoView ... x:Name="myUserControl"/>
```

and use it in code behind

```
public MainWindow() 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Game.DateInfoModel = new DateInfoModel();
    myUserControl.DataContext = new DateInfoViewModel(Game.DateInfoModel);
}
```

I would however suggest **3rd solution** where you create bigger view model, with smaller view models as its properties, set it as `DataContext` of the whole window and in XAML bind `DataContext` of specific `UserControl(s)` to properties of bigger view model. Like that you have to set `DataContext` only once and it will propagate to all other controls in the window.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
view.DataContext = viewModel;
```

to

```
this.DataContext = viewModel;
```

as you need to set the DataContext of MainWindow if the UserControl is located in that

Comment: This works, however it makes me wonder how I would implement several views in my MainWindow, each with their own viewmodel.

Comment: @gartenriese this solves your problem by coincidence. You have one instance of `DateInfoView` in XAML and one that you create in code (that you don't use after). You can set `DataContext` of `UserControl` just as well but it needs to be same instance for example by referring to control by name.

Comment: @dkozl: Yes, I just found that out thanks to your comment earlier. If you post an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @dkozl it doesn't solve the problem by coincidence but by the information given in the original question.

Comment: Maybe wording is a bit wrong but setting `DataContext` on user control is not the problem here. Setting it on correct instance is